# Automate AWS ECR scanning

Tags: python, amazon-ecr, scanning

I have tried to automate ECR image scanning using AWS CLI. But I was stuck in the scanning step. When I call `aws ecr start-image-scan`, it starts the scanning. But how I know the scanning is finish. My images are large and it takes few minutes. Could someone help me to figure out this. I am using Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. You have to call `aws ecr wait image-scan-complete` api call after you start the scanning.
This `aws ecr wait image-scan-complete` command will wait till the scan is completed.

```
def wait_scan_results(repo_name, image_Digest):
    wait_scan_cmd = f"aws ecr wait image-scan-complete --repository-name {repo_name} --image-id imageDigest={image_Digest}"
    wait_scan = subprocess.Popen(wait_scan_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    wait_scan.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Please check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5Aaj2uPeeo , this shows how to automate ECR image scanning from A to Z using Python

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aws ecr wait [image-scan-complete]` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/wait/image-scan-complete.html#image-scan-complete). But it has some limitations.

> It will poll every 5 seconds until a successful state has been reached. This will exit with a return code of 255 after 60 failed checks.

Another solution you can use Eventbridge to cache ECR Scanning complete. [ecr-event-bridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr-eventbridge.html#ecr-eventbridge-bus)

generate an event like

```json
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "85fc3613-e913-7fc4-a80c-a3753e4aa9ae",
    "detail-type": "ECR Image Scan",
    "source": "aws.ecr",
    "account": "123456789012",
    "time": "2019-10-29T02:36:48Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:123456789012:repository/my-repository-name"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "scan-status": "COMPLETE",
        "repository-name": "my-repository-name",
        "finding-severity-counts": {
           "CRITICAL": 10,
           "MEDIUM": 9
         },
        "image-digest": "sha256:7f5b2640fe6fb4f46592dfd3410c4a79dac4f89e4782432e0378abcd1234",
        "image-tags": []
    }
}
```